# Android keyboard input method

Tags: android

i want to detect whether Arabic keyboard is installed in device or not. how it is possible. i want to check if Arabic keyboard is available other wise give link to install it first.

Answer (score 1):

InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 List InputMethods = manager.getInputMethodList();

This will give list of input method in device.
-check for Arabic keyboard packagename/.classname